# FxCop(CA1800) warnings are not suppressed properly

Tags: c#, fxcop, suppress-warnings

I have implemented the source, it contains some CA1800(DoNotCastUnnecessarily) warnings. I can't able to fix this warning in source, so I try to suppress the warning by adding suppress code in the method.

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily", Justification = "Ignored this warning")]
```

When build the project in visual studio 2015, the warnings are not shown. But when run with fxcop tool, it generates this warning.

How can I properly ignore the warning when I build with fxcop tool in server side also?

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed the project file(.csproj) which contains the DebugType is none, so the suppressed codes are not detected. When change the DebugType to full, now the suppressed code properly working.

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
```